# Send Commands TO Cortana with VB.NET

Tags: cortana

I understand the concept of having Cortana launch apps, etc...BUT, is there a way to have my app send a command ***back*** to Cortana?

One idea is to have a batch for the start of the day:

Send to Cortana ("What is the weather forecast for today")
--wait command
Send to Cortana ("What is my schedule for today")
--wait command
Send to Cortana ("Read Headline News")

Just a thought on getting my daily updates without asking over and over.

Comment: I'd check in the control panel list of file associations and protocols (the protocols are at the bottom of the long list) what protocols Cortana supports. Then check out those, do some experimenting. You can probably just use `ShellExecute` API function to launch an URI with the relevant protocol. Can't test since I'm working at old Windows 7 laptop due to Windows 10 killing the newer Dell laptop. Silly Windows 10 insisted on repairing a graphics card / driver problem each reboot, by way of rebooting. And again. And so on. Jeez. "We know bestest for you". It had worked fine that way!

Comment: Currently, there isn't any documented mechanism to send commands to Cortana on a user's behalf this way.